# Combining many for loops into one

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop

I am dealing with a problem for which, originally, I will need to use nested `for` loop. I was wondering whether there is a way to combine a large number of `for` loops into one.

To add to this, I have found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27138616/avoiding-nested-for-loops-in-matlab), but it requires generating all possible combinations first, which, might be bad in terms of memory requirements. My `for` loops consist of many variables independent from each other, with which a cost function is evaluated, such as:

```
for x1 = 1:10
    for x2 = 2:15
        for x3 = 3:5
            for x4 = 7:9
                %and so on
                cost = J(x1, x2, x3, x4) %or more
            end
        end
    end
end
```

If I know in advance how many variables I need to use, is there a way to make this block simpler?

Comment: You can optimize a loop *depending* on what it does. If there was a general way of making nested loops a single one then there would not be nested loops to start with. Also, try to avoid unnecessary formating.

Comment: To add to my previous comment. Almost all code optimization will rely in the weak balance between memory and computational time. Generally you need to choose one and be aware that the other one will likely get worse.

Comment: Another alternative is to modify `J()` to accept vectors and return a n-dim (n being the number of variable supplied) tensor, but that too goes back to a balance between memory and time.

Comment: You could do this beautifully with iterators in Python (keeping memory complexity low) - but as far as I know an equivalent construct does not exist in Matlab.

Comment: @Florian Iterators would indeed be very useful in this case.

Comment: Alternatively, just combine the idea suggested by mpaskov and the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27138616/avoiding-nested-for-loops-in-matlab. meshgrid or ndgrid the first couple of parameters and then do the same in `J()` and combine the results. This will minimize your for loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function does the job but it will be slower then the original code

```
function loop(f, args, varargin)
if ~isempty(args)
    for arg = args{1}
        loop(f, args(2:end), varargin{:}, arg);
    end
else
    f(varargin{:});
end
```

You can start your calculation with

```
loop(@J, {1:10, 2:15, 3:5, 7:9});
```

Comment: It might make my code slower, but it's a very neat solution, thus I'm accepting this answer.